# Determine Linear Independence

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose 2x +3y = 0, 3x+2y=5

Let P = $\begin{bmatrix}2\\3\end{bmatrix}$
Q = $\begin{bmatrix}3\\2\end{bmatrix}$
and X = $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$

Are P & Q Linearly independent or dependent?

I thought it was dependent because 
c1$\begin{bmatrix}2\\3\end{bmatrix}$ + c2$\begin{bmatrix}3\\2\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}0\\5\end{bmatrix}$

with c1 = 3 & c2 = -2. So there is a non-zero solution X, but apparently the answer is they are independent. Can someone tell me where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the vectors to be linearly dependent there must exist $\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{K}$

$$\lambda\cdot\begin{bmatrix}2\\3\end{bmatrix}+\mu\cdot\begin{bmatrix}3\\2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

Obviously since you are considering $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ this is not the case.

Furthermore you can easily check it by calculating the determinant of matrix (since by the rule of the determinant this should be equal to zero if the columns (considered as vector set) are linearly dependent):

$$\det\bigg(\begin{bmatrix}2\ 3\\3\ 2\end{bmatrix}\bigg)=-2\ne0$$

Comment: Can you check linear dependence of any size matrix by comparing the det to 0?

Comment: Since the determinant is only defined for square matrices the answer is no. Yet you can easily compute the $rank$ of the matrix through Gaussian Elimination tecnique and check if the matrix has full rank (linearly independent) or not (linearly dependent).

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing linearly independent/dependent vectors with a system that has a solution. Your work shows that $x=3,y=-2$ is a solution to your system of equations. To show two vectors are linearly independent, you need to show that the only solution of $c_1 P+c_2 Q = \bar{0}$ (where $\bar{0}$ is the vector of all zeroes) is $c_1=c_2=0$. If this equation has a solution with one or both of the $c_i \neq 0$, then the vectors are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0):

They are independent because there is no solution to $$c_1\begin{bmatrix}2\\3\end{bmatrix}+c_2\begin{bmatrix}3\\2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$ Note that this is different from having a solution to the *system* which you are solving. In fact, given that they are linearly independent in a vector space of dimension 2, you can conclude that they form a basis and hence the system will have one unique solution.